# This application has requested the RunTime.....?

Tags: c++

I developed C++ code on Windows Server 2008. I was running that exe on Windows Xp. I am getting the Runtime Error C++ "This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way. Please contact the application's support team for more information". Could you please tell me the reason why I am getting this error.

Comment: To get rid of this error, you can accept answers to your previous questions.

Comment: There are a million reasons your program could crash, and we're suppose to just guess which of those applies to your code? You need to debug your application and find out what's making it crash.

Answer (score 1):

You'll almost certainly need to run the code *under the debugger* on the Operating System that you're encountering the problem on to diagnose why you're receiving this error. There are other ways of determining the error, such as memory dumps, but given that you have full access to the source-code and to, seemingly, the machine the error is occuring on, examining its behaviour under the debugger would be your best bet.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't run it under the debugger, you could try running it using dependencywalker (www.dependencywalker.com). That will show you if there are any dlls missing and give you some idea what the program was doing when it crashed.

Comment: +1. I would bet on this being a missing DLL dependency.  Probably missing the C++ runtimes, or trying to use a debug build.